# Why “os” and not “vos”?

Tags: etimología, pronombres, historia

The direct and indirect object pronoun in the first person plural is *nos*, obviously related to *nosotros*. Why is, then, the second person plural *os*, since *vos* would make more sense in order to correspond with *vosotros*? (I know that *vos* is used in certain dialects of Spanish, but it is not used as the direct or indirect object pronoun.)

Answer (score 6):

The pronoun *os* developed during the Middle Ages as a shorter form of *vos* to be used after verb conjugations which ended in a consonant. This often meant the imperative, ending in *-d*. It first appears like this in writings of the 13th century.

The cluster *-dv-* (phonetically [db]) was (and is) very unusual in Spanish, so the speakers first simplified it by dropping the *-v-* and then began generalizing this form to all positions. By the 16th century *vos* as the object pronoun had almost disappeared.

Source: *[Forms of Address in the Spanish of the Americas](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=zgHXDAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA37&ots=GCrcaNq6qH&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false)*.