# ¿Por qué "abogado" se escribe con "b" si viene del latín "advocātus"?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, letras, latín, betacismo

Resulta que abogado se escribe con *b*:

> [**abogado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=07TG2dg)
>
> ```
>  Del lat. advocātus.
> ```
>
> 1. m. y f. Licenciado en derecho que ofrece profesionalmente asesoramiento jurídico y que ejerce la defensa de las partes en los procesos judiciales o en los procedimientos administrativos.
> 2. m. y f. Intercesor o mediador.
> 3. m. y f. Nic. Persona habladora, enredadora, parlanchina.

No tendría mayor relevancia si no viéramos que viene del latín *advocātus* y que casi todos [los otros idiomas provinientes de esa raíz mantienen tal letra](https://twitter.com/calqueraun/status/996053539628691461). Aunque bueno, ya vimos en [¿Por qué escribimos "móvil" con "v", si viene del latín "mobĭlis" y el resto de idiomas mantuvieron la "b"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/24234/1674) que tampoco esto es mayor problema :)

Mirando en el NTLLE, veo entradas de *avogado* en los años 1617 (Minsheu), 1705 (Sobrino), 1706 (Stevens), 1786 (Terreros y Pando) y 1933 (Academia Histórico).
En cuanto a *abogado*, ya se le ve en 1495 (Nebrija).

El DLE tiene algunas otras palabras de la misma raíz, todas marcadas en desuso:

- [*advocación*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0su2Uib) *4. f. desus. abogacía (‖ profesión y ejercicio del abogado).*
- [*advocar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0svLaPF) *1. intr. desus. abogar.*

Además, en el DLE hay multitud de entradas que empiezan por *adv* (no veo cómo puedo enlazar la página que genera).

¿Tendrá que ver esta *simplificación* con lo que comentaba pablodf76 en [Why “os” and not “vos”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23703/1674)?

> The cluster *-dv-* (phonetically [db]) was (and is) very unusual in Spanish, so the speakers first simplified it by dropping the *-v-* and then began generalizing this form to all positions.

Comment: _Beati hispani quibus vivere est bibere._

Comment: En *abogado* se simplificó /db/ en /b/, no como en el caso del *vos* enclítico. Es un cambio más esperable. Lo otro creo que se debe a los azares de la ortografía, pero me gustaría leer una respuesta mejor. :)

Comment: Pasa algo similar con _avus_ y _abuelo_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Spelling in the time of Betacism

During the evolution of Spanish, in the period where it lost the distinction between 'b' and 'v', words etymologically containing b/p/v/u were usually spelled as they were **pronounced**, i.e. 'b' for [b] and 'v/u' for [β]:

- *cantava, cavallo, (h)aver/auer, seruir*
- *boca, bueno, lobo (< lupus), abeja (< apicŭla)*

## Spelling reforms

However, in the 18th century the RAE instigated some spelling reforms to make such words closer match their etymological roots, which is why there is such etymological regularity today:

> La concepción de la RAE se hizo evidente en su Diccionario de autoridades, publicado a lo largo de la década de 1720, en que el buen decir se recaba de la obra de un canon bien seleccionado de autores y eruditos. Bajo la influencia del salmantino Adrián Cónnink, el *Diccionario de autoridades* rompió de cuajo con la tendencia fonetista y recuperó los principios que la Académie française había empleado para fijar la lengua francesa: la etimología y la pronunciación histórica. **De ese modo, restauró la diferencia entre *b* y *v* a pesar de que fonológicamente había desaparecido,** impuso grafías latinizantes para los vocablos de origen griego ―*th* para las *θ* etimológicas, *rh* para las *ρ*, *ps* para las *ψ, ph* para las *φ*―, recuperó las *h* mudas y fijó la grafía de los grupos consonánticos en atención a su origen.

#### Exceptions

Some words managed to escape this reformation and maintained their 'as pronounced' spellings, due to popular use, oversight, or erroneous etymology:

- *basura < vassura < versūram* (initial [β] [became [b]](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25689/18348) in the 15th century)
- *avanzar < abanzar/avanzar < *abantiāre*
- *averío < haberío* (influence of *ave*)

## Simplification of consonant clusters

In the evolution from Latin to Spanish, the 'db' in *ad* + *b...* words was mostly simplified to 'b':

- *abajar < abaxar < adbassio*
- *abrazar < *adbracchiō*

However, in some *ad* + *v...*/*u...* words the 'dv' was simplified to a mix of 'v' and 'b':

- *[avezar/abezar](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=avezar%2Cabezar&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) < *advitio*
- *[aviltar/abiltar](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aviltar%2Cabiltar&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) < *vilĭtas*
- *abogar/avocar < advoco*

*Abogado* just happens to be one of these words that had enough popular coinage to avoid being reformed:

> [image]
>
> - [*Reflexiones sobre el Estilo*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=5N5DAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA194&dq=avogado+abogado), Johann Daniel Wagener (1811)

> [image]
>
> - [*Diccionario etimológico de la lengua castellana: (ensayo) precedido de unos ...*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=lbJ7TahXEwUC&pg=PA464&dq=avogado+abogado), Pedro Felipe Monlau (1856)

---

#### Note: Learned borrowings

In some *ad* + *v...* words the 'd' remains however, due to being learned borrowings from Late Latin. With these there is often a Spanishised doublet more organically inherited as well:

- *avenir/advenir < advenio*
- *averar/adverar < adverare*
- *abogar/avocar/advocar < advoco*
- *adverbio < adverbium*
- *adverar < *advērāre*
- *advertir < adverto*

Answer (score 4):

Estoy viendo que en el CORDE aparecen unos cuantos casos de *advogado* (o *aduogado*) y derivados, como este:

> *Y el Rey solamente remitió mil ducados al advogado fiscal para gastos criminales, con tantas piguilas, que apenas se hizo alguno dellos.*
>
> Luis Cabrera de Córdoba, "Historia de Felipe II, rey de España", c1619 (España).

No hay casos mucho más allá, siendo el más reciente que encuentro de 1625. Estos casos coinciden en el tiempo con los casos de *avogado*, sin la *d*, como el siguiente:

> *El emperador escogió y nombró para juezes de possessión al licenciado Acuña [...]; hizo avogado al licenciado Juan Rodríguez de Pisa, fiscal al doctor Ribera, y secretario a Bartholomé Ruyz de Castañeda.*
>
> Francisco López de Gómara, "La primera parte de la Historia natural de las Indias", 1554 (España).

Los casos de *avogado* no van más allá de 1626, aunque hay uno de *auogado* de 1705:

> *En la ziudad de Burgos a veinte y seis de octubre, año de mil setezientos y zinco, el señor lizenziado don Francisco López de Murillas, auogado de los Reales Consejos, theniente de correxidor desta ziudad y su xurisdicción por Su Magestad [...].*
>
> Anónimo, "Acta de 29-X-1705 [Documentos de teatro en Burgos (1700-1752)]", 1705 (España).

En ambos casos el número total de ejemplos encontrados no van más allá de unas cuantas docenas. En cambio, si buscas *abogado* salen miles de ejemplos incluso limitando la búsqueda a textos anteriores a 1600. Ejemplo:

> *E demás, dióles Spíritu Santo por abogado que los lenguajes que non entendiesen nin sabíen fablar, que ge los feziese entender e saber.*
>
> Alfonso X, "Setenario", c1252-1270 (España).

O este que parece más claro, también del siglo XIII:

> *Preguntaron a Martín Alfonso que por qué lo mandara desafiar, dixo Pero Lopes de Fontecha, que era abogado de Martín Alfonso, que non auýa ya por qué lo dezir, que muchas cosas le pudiera fazer porque le sería vergüença de las dezir, así commo yazerle con la muger o acometerle su cuerpo, mas abasaua asaz que'l tenýa desafiado quando lo mató.*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro de los fueros de Castiella", a1284 (España).

Parece poco probable que sean errores de transcripción, dado que el texto pone *había* como *auýa*, respetando la u/v de entonces, mientras que sí que pone *abogado*.

Como nota, también aparece una docena de casos de *adbogado*, el más reciente de 1679.

Así pues, parece que la forma dominante de la palabra ya en el siglo XIII era *abogado*. Esto se atestigua, como bien dices, con la entrada de *abogado* en el diccionario de Nebrija de 1495. Covarrubias en 1611 recoge *abogado*, *abogar* y *abogacía*.

El verbo *abogar* se usaba (y usa) como:

> Defender los Abogados en juicio las causas y pleitos, y alegar de la justicia, ù derecho de las partes, que se valen de ellos para este fin.

Sin embargo, existía otro verbo muy similar que significaba otra cosa distinta:

> AVOCAR. Llamar ante sí algun Tribunal superior, y traher los autos de alguna causa, citando las partes litigantes, y sacando el processo de otro Tribunal inferior.

Esta venía del latín *avocare*, aunque también existía *advocar* que venía de *advocare*:

> ADVOCAR. Llamar hacia sí, atraher, ò mover à alguno.

Con esta información, ¿qué dirías que es un *advocado*? Parecería que se refiere a alguien que es llamado (atraído o invocado por un tribunal), pero no, el *Diccionario de Autoridades* dice que es lo mismo que *abogado*. Confuso, ¿no? ¿Y *avocado* entonces? Era sencillamente el participio pasado de *avocar*.

¿Qué dirías que significa la siguiente frase del *Vidal Mayor* de 1250?

> Et otrosí el aduocado deue ser puesto ante l'alcalde, seyendo present el aduersario, o deue ser feito público instrumento al poner del aduocado.
>   ("El *advocado* debe ser puesto ante el alcalde, estando presente el adversario.")

¿"Advocado" aquí entonces qué es? ¿Abogado o invocado? Pues parece que *abogado*, y así descubrimos que en los siglos XIII y XIV resulta que *advocado* era bastante común, al menos en algunos textos donde se habla de *advocato procurador* (siendo *procurador* sinónima de *abogado defensor*).

Así pues, tenemos que en un momento en el que España estaba dividida en reinos, algunos textos usan *abogado*, otros *advogado*, otros *advocato*... alguna tenía que imponerse, y seguramente el hecho de que existía un verbo *advocar*, que acabó tomando otro significado allá por el siglo XVI, ayudó para que se acabara distinguiendo una palabra de otra, adoptándose la forma con *b* de *abogado*.

---

Nota: la conclusión es una suposición mía. Me faltaría encontrar alguna fuente fiable que lo corrobore. Y claro, faltaría por saber cómo es que en el siglo XIII la forma dominante ya era *abogado*.